# Django default queryset values shorthand

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am initializing variables to `None` as default value. If the queryset returns no objects then the program will not fail.

Is there a shorter method on this? Thanks

```
  qs_data = {
        'flal_id_no' : None,
        'mail_id_no' : None,
        'subject_id_no':None,
        'pdsbj_id_no':None,
    }

    qs = vFileAllocation.objects.values().filter(track_id_no=get_track_id_no)[0]

    if qs:
        qs_data['flal_id_no'] = qs['flal_id_no']
        qs_data['mail_id_no'] = qs['mlal_id_no']
        qs_data['subject_id_no'] = qs['subject_id_no']
        qs_data['pdsbj_id_no'] = qs['pdsbj_id_no']
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic python **or** operator (*return default if None*) can be used:

`queryset[0]` - gets first object from the queryset result, so in case no matches found - queryset will contain ***no elements*** (`queryset == <QuerySet[]>`) and getting first element from it `[0]` ***will fail***.

Correct way is to use **`.first()`** on queryset to evaluate it and get first result or `None`.

For this example this can be done as a one-liner:

```
qs_data = vFileAllocation.objects.values() \
    .filter(track_id_no=get_track_id_no) \
    .first() or qs_data
```

or

```
qs = vFileAllocation.objects.values() \
    .filter(track_id_no=get_track_id_no).first()
# qs is already evaluated
qs_data = qs or qs_data
```

- Fixed answer thanks to @csandreas1 comment

Comment: Do not confuse `[0]` with `[:0]`. `[0]` is the index of the queryset which is always 0, because there's always 1 queryset

Comment: If i want to perform a query that returns multiple records `first()` will only return one row?

Comment: Yes. `first()` will return either first object or None.

Comment: Yes but i expect to fetch multiple records. Otherwise i would use `get(pk=...)`

Comment: In the question first result is retrieved with [0] and dict values are set as if qs is single row.

Comment: `qs = Model.objects.filter.all() or [qs_data]` - for multiple. This way qs will be a list, so futher has to be processed like a list - `for obj in qs: ...`.